# MFC: How do you determine which CBCGPDockingControlBar is active/has focus?

Tags: winapi, mfc, bcg

Using BCGControlBar Pro using a wizard created app with multiple `CBCGPDockingControlBar` windows.   My question is, how do I tell which one is active or has the focus?  The normal `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetFocus()` report the main frame.

Thanks.

Comment: By simply enumerating all your created controlbars, and test it for `GetFocus()` or similar.

Comment: Does this docking control bar has any child windows that may get a focus?

Comment: yes the docking control bar has a child window that can get focus, one's a tree, ones property grid, another is output bar with rich text control.   I guess I could setup a global static var and for each control type capture OnFocus to set which one has it.  But seems like I should be able to somehow enumerate the control bars and check if it "hasfocus" but didn't see that available.

Comment: You don't need such a global variable. GetFocus from inside your main thread should do the work. It does so in my application.